# Find the field type using Jackson JSON

Tags: java, reflection, annotations, jackson

I am trying to do reflection using Jackson. 
More specifically, I would like to retrieve the type,name, and value of every field in a particular class. I am able to get the name and the value of a field using `ObjectMapper`, but I can't seem to find a method to retrieve the type. My code is listed below:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

University uni = new University();
String uniJSON = mapper.writeValueAsString(uni);
System.out.println(uniJSON);
```

Output:

```js
{"name":null,"ae":{"annotationExampleNumber":0},"noOfDepartments":0,"departments":null}
```

Comment: You want the output json to hold a property with the class name? Maybe you can show us the output you are expecting...

Answer (score 1):

You could use [generateJsonSchema](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.8.8/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper.html#generateJsonSchema%28java.lang.Class%29) method as follows

```
try{
    ObjectMapper json=new ObjectMapper();
    json.configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    System.out.println(json.generateJsonSchema(University.class).toString());
}catch(Exception e){
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

This produces a json schema which you could read to get field data types. Be aware that this method generates a [JSON](http://www.json.org/) schema, hence, it only uses JSON allowed data types (string, number, boolean, object, array and null).

If you want the Java Types, you should use reflection. Be warned, there are complex issues like circular references, arrays, etc. If you know the name of the property you're trying to identify its type, you could do something similar to this. This works with nested properties if you pass on a parameter like "principal.name"

```
private Class<?> getPropertyType(Class<?> clazz,String property){
try{
    LinkedList<String> properties=new LinkedList<String>();
    properties.addAll(Arrays.asList(property.split("\\.")));
    Field field = null;
    while(!properties.isEmpty()){
        field = clazz.getDeclaredField(properties.removeFirst());
        clazz=field.getType();
    }
    return field.getType();
}catch(Exception e){
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Annotate your domain classes with Jackson annotations to do that:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include=JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property="type")
public class University {
```

See this for more info:
http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2010/03/entry_372.html